# Finding the second and fourth Tuesday of the month with Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, calendar

My association has meetings on the second and fourth Tuesday of each month and I'd really like a Javascript code so I don't have to update our site every two weeks and the date of the next meeting can be calculated and displayed automatically.

I'd really appreciate some help, as I have absolutely no skils in Javascript, only in CSS and HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution

HTML

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Javascript

```
function getTuesdays(month, year) {
    var d = new Date(year, month, 1),
        tuesdays = [];

    d.setDate(d.getDate() + (9 - d.getDay()) % 7)
    while (d.getMonth() === month) {
        tuesdays.push(new Date(d.getTime()));
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
    }

    return tuesdays;
}

var meetingTuesdays = [],
    ul = document.getElementById("list"),
    temp,
    li,
    i;

for ( i = 0; i < 12; i += 1) {
    temp = getTuesdays(i, 2013);
    meetingTuesdays.push(temp[1]);
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = temp[1];
    ul.appendChild(li);

    meetingTuesdays.push(temp[3]);
    li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = temp[3];
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

console.log(meetingTuesdays);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/txDYy/)

Update: a further demonstration for you

Javascript

```
function getTuesdays(month, year) {
    var d = new Date(year, month, 1),
        tuesdays = [];

    d.setDate(d.getDate() + (9 - d.getDay()) % 7)
    while (d.getMonth() === month) {
        tuesdays.push(new Date(d.getTime()));
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
    }

    return tuesdays;
}

var today = new Date(),
    theseTuesdays = getTuesdays(today.getMonth(), today.getFullYear()),
    next;

theseTuesdays.some(function (tuesday, index) {
    if (index % 2 === 1 && tuesday > today) {
        next = tuesday;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});

alert("Our next meeting is on : " + moment(next).format("MMMM Do YYYY"));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/WyV4t/)

Comment: That's almost what I'm looking for, but I only want to display one date a time.

Comment: The idea is:
"Our next meeting is on : [date]"

Comment: So, just pick a month and format the result as you want, this example just gets all of them. Use the getTuesdays() function, it will return all the tuesdays for that month and year. I just looped through the whole year to get them all for you. I even included moments.js for you in my jsfiddle to make formatting easier, http://momentjs.com/