# Given a date (m/d/yyyy) determine if its "the third tuesday" of the month etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

After several searches, I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for. Im using `jquery datepicker` to return a date string that looks like `Day, Month Date, YYYY`, and I am looking for a library or some method that will take that and turn it into 
`the second Tuesday of the month`, or `the fourth Thursday of the month`. So far it seems like jquery's `prettyDate` and `EasyDate` dont have the functionality I'm looking for, and I would love to avoid doing this by hand!

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I've only used it for basic things, so I'm not sure if it will solve all your needs, but you could check out: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: doesn't look like it has the functionality of "nth mon/tues/etc of the month"

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16467099/592253

Comment: these are better answers than the question it duplicated.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need a date library - just take the date, divide by 7 and round up.

```
//format: Day, Month Date, YYYY
var ordinals = ["", "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth"];
var date = "Friday, May 10, 2013";
var tokens = date.split(/[ ,]/);
// tokens = ["Friday", "", "May", "10", "", "2013"];
console.log( "The " + ordinals[Math.ceil(tokens[3]/7)] + " " + tokens[0] + " of the month");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function nthDay(D){
    var nth= ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', 'Fifth'], 
    dayNames= ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 
    'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'], 
    monthNames= ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 
    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    return nth[Math.floor(D.getDate()/7)]+'  '+
    dayNames[D.getDay()]+' of '+monthNames[D.getMonth()];
}
```

**nthDay(new Date(2013, 4, 10))**

/*  returned value: 
Second  Friday of May
*/

Comment: This fails.  http://jsfiddle.net/7pd3vebc/  That's the first Monday of September. Use ceil and leave first array member blank- > http://jsfiddle.net/xka6hab9/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I used back in the day, if momentjs doesn't work out for you (although I really think momentjs is a better solution).

```
/*
Parameters:
index: n'th occurrence of the specified day
day: daynumber - javascript way where sunday is 0 and is saturday is 6
month: javascript way which is 0-11 [optional - defaults to current]
year: Full year - four digits [optional - defaults to current]
*/
function getNthDayOfMonth(index,day,month,year){
// Create date object
var date = new Date();
// Set to first day of month
date.setDate(1);
// If supplied - set the month  
if(month!==''&&month!==undefined){
    // Set month
    date.setMonth(month);
}else{
    month = date.getMonth();
}
// If supplied - set the year   
if(year!==''&&year!==undefined){
    // Set year
    date.setFullYear(year);
}else{
    year = date.getFullYear();
}
// Find daynumber
firstDay = date.getDay();
// Find first friday.
while(date.getDay()!=day){      
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+1) ;
}
switch(index){
    case 2:
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+7);         
    break;
    case 3:
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+14);                
    break;
    case 4:
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+21);
    break;
    case 5:
        date.setDate(date.getDate()+28);
        if(date.getMonth()!==month){
            date = null;
        }
    break;
}
return date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Date.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation) you have some helpful functions like `moveToFirstDayOfMonth` and  `getWeek`.

Then you can get the week of the first day of the month and subtract those two to get the week of the month.

Here is a simple example using Date.js and going off of today but you can pass in your own date. I am not too familiar with other Date libraries but I think you can recreate something like this below.

```
function dayOfWeekToday(){
    //Get the total weeks on the year from this day
    var totalWeek = Date.today().getWeek();

    //Get the first day of this month
    var firstOfMonth = Date.today().moveToFirstDayOfMonth();

    //Get the total weeks form the first day of the month
    var weeksAtStartOfMonth = firstOfMonth.getWeek();
    //Get the week of the month
    var week = totalWeek - weeksAtStartOfMonth;

    //Get the day(0-6) of today and the first day
    var today = Date.today().getDay();
    var firstDay = firstOfMonth.getDay();

    //If today is before the firstDay then the week will be off by one
    if(today < firstDay){
        week--;
    }
    //Get the day form of the string
    var day = Date.today().toString("dddd");

    //Translate from a number to a string
    var str = "first";
    if(week === 1){
            str = "second";
    }else if(week === 2){
        str = "third";
    }else if(week === 3){
        str = "fourth";
    }else if (week === 4){
        str = "fifth";
    }
    //Result
    return "The "+str+" "+day+" of the month";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some simple logic that just works backwards from the value of the date:

```
function calculateNthDate(startDateDay, startDateValue){
  var day = startDateDay;
  var date = startDateValue;
  var i = 0;

  while(date  >= 0){

      if (date > 0 ){
          i++;
      }
      date = date - 7;
  }
  var string = "The "+i+'th '+day+" of the month.";   
}
```

edit: the `th` will have to be customized for `nd`, `st`, and `rd` .